# WPF selectable curve

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drawing, bezier

I am currently working on a graph like editor application. So far I got nodes and connection showing, I can move them etc.
I would like to be able to select the curves connecting one node to another, the orange one.

[image]

Selecting the curve itself , is not the real problem, it is just a bit tricky since it is a fairly thin object (original stroke thickness was 2). I had to fatten up the Stroke to make it somewhat easier to select. I would like to keep the stroke smaller because I think it looks better.
My idea was to draw two curves, one with a high stroke thickness but transparent, on top of that, the actual colored curve. This would allow me to basically have a tolerance in how close i need to click to the actual curve to select it.

Right now the curve (Connection) is a class inheriting from Shape, in order to have two of them I wrapped them in a custom control. It did the trick, the thing I don't like about it is the fact that I had to wrap all the properties on may custom shape in order to propagate the data to both my Connections, for example I had to wrap the Start and End point property.
I can probably achieve that trough bindings as well but that is basically moving the problem from code behind to XAML.

Is it there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do? I am not an expert use in WPF so I might have overlooked some simple solution. Any feedback on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

M.

Comment: You have a lot of test masking the actual question: what's your actual question? "How can I click on the curve and have it register as a click"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all I think your way to do it is the easyest one. But you got me interested and I have explored another way to select an element. Of course probably it needs a lot of work to adjust it, but maybe gets you on the track of an alternative way.

My idea is based on `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest`. It performs a hit test in the point you indicate and returns the Dependency Objects found in that point. So what i've done is listening to MouseRightButtonDown event (in my example in a Window) and, from the point where the Right Mouse button is pressed, i calculate a grid of points forming a circular grid. Then I HitTest each of those points and if i find a known named Path, i can safely select it.

After this (too long) explanation, here comes a sample code:

```
List<DependencyObject> hitResultsList = new List<DependencyObject>();
private void WrapPanel_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Window wp = sender as Window;
    // Retrieve the coordinate of the mouse position.
    Point pt = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

    bool elementFound = false;
    foreach (Point point in GetPointsInCircle(pt, 8, pt, new Point(2, 2)))
    {
         // Clear the contents of the list used for hit test results.
         Debug.Print(point.ToString());
         hitResultsList.Clear();
         // Set up a callback to receive the hit test result enumeration.
         VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(wp, null,
                new HitTestResultCallback(MyHitTestResult),
                new PointHitTestParameters(point));

         // Perform actions on the hit test results list.
         foreach (DependencyObject d in hitResultsList)
         {
             if (d is Path)
             {
                 Path p = d as Path;
                 if (p.Name == "link1")
                 {
                     elementFound = true; //Here we found the Path with name link1, we could then select it
                     break;
                  }
              }
         }
         if (elementFound) break;
   }

}
```

MyHitTestResult:

```
// Return the result of the hit test to the callback.
public HitTestResultBehavior MyHitTestResult(HitTestResult result)
{
    // Add the hit test result to the list that will be processed after the enumeration.
    hitResultsList.Add(result.VisualHit);

    // Set the behavior to return visuals at all z-order levels.
    return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
}
```

GetPointsInCircle (Gets a circular grid of points):

```
private static IEnumerable<Point> GetPointsInCircle(Point circleCenter, float radius, Point gridCenter, Point gridStep)
{
    if (radius <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("radius", "Argument must be positive.");
    }
    if (gridStep.X <= 0 || gridStep.Y <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("gridStep", "Argument must contain positive components only.");
    }

    // Loop bounds for X dimension:
    int i1 = (int)Math.Ceiling((circleCenter.X - gridCenter.X - radius) / gridStep.X);
    int i2 = (int)Math.Floor((circleCenter.X - gridCenter.X + radius) / gridStep.X);

    // Constant square of the radius:
    float radius2 = radius * radius;

    for (int i = i1; i <= i2; i++)
    {
        // X-coordinate for the points of the i-th circle segment:
        double x = gridCenter.X + i * gridStep.X;

        // Local radius of the circle segment (half-length of chord) calulated in 3 steps.
        // Step 1. Offset of the (x, *) from the (circleCenter.x, *):
        double localRadius = circleCenter.X - x;
        // Step 2. Square of it:
        localRadius *= localRadius;
        // Step 3. Local radius of the circle segment:
        localRadius = (float)Math.Sqrt(radius2 - localRadius);

        // Loop bounds for Y dimension:
        int j1 = (int)Math.Ceiling((circleCenter.Y - gridCenter.Y - localRadius) / gridStep.Y);
        int j2 = (int)Math.Floor((circleCenter.Y - gridCenter.Y + localRadius) / gridStep.Y);

        for (int j = j1; j <= j2; j++)
        {
            yield return new Point(x, gridCenter.Y + j * gridStep.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

References:

[HitTest on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608753(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Get all points on a uniform discrete grid inside a circle's radius (Adapted)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70540/get-all-points-on-a-uniform-discrete-grid-inside-a-circles-radius)

Comment: Interesting approach, I did not think of it, It is slightly "brute force" but I think it will do the trick. the only worry i have is that if the line is thin, I will need to generate a dense grid, which  scale in a quadratic way. Now the good thing is that I might still sample a small part, and the problem doesn't scale with the amount of nodes/connection i have in the scene which si good. Hit test might not be heavy neither if WPF uses an offscreen render with unique ides. I am gonna try and see what comes out of it! thanks!

Comment: @MarcoGiordano Well, in the test project i've made I'm generating a 8 pixel radius grid with a 2 pixel step and it works pretty fast. You have to think also that your curve is not going to be usually a straight line and being a circle grid, your chances that a point on the grid is on top on your curve are very likely. Also, you could change this a bit to archive a "magnet effect", that is, when you detect your curve, move the mouse pointer to the point detected. That could be very cool :)

Answer (score -1):

One quick thought might be to render a transparent thicker curve beneath your existing curves. WPF's hit test system may still pick up the clicks on the transparency and give you the effect of having some invisible 'glow' around what's visually rendered which a user can still click on to interact with.

Comment: yeah that s the exact approach i mentioned above, the problem is that I will need to wrap the two objects inside another class and make it behave as one, aka wrapping all the properties and stuff, which i don't find it so elegant, but might be a personal taste, that s why I was looking for alternative solutions.